# Creating mysql table with java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create a table using java for mysql. The code is below.

```
  Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();

  String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + libcard +
               "(Title INTEGER, " +
               " Director VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " dateBorrowed DATE, " + 
               " dueDate DATE)"; 

  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

but there is always error. :: Exception message is given below :_

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '23232.0(Title INTEGER,  Director VARCHAR(255),  dateBorrowed DATE,  dueDate DATE' at line 1

Comment: What kind of table name is `23232.0`?

Comment: @juergend: I'm guessing (hoping) it's a typo rather than a table name...

Comment: The error message is probably copied from the output. That is no typo IMO.

Comment: @Izmaki: It is however a *valid* (albeit stupid) table name - one merely need quote it (with backticks).

Comment: @eggyal: I'm not saying it's invalid or wrong, I'm saying it's meaningless.

Comment: @lzmaki if you don't know the domain, no way of saying it is meaningless. It could be a table holding data of object number 23232.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) on how to come up with valid table names. In your case `23232.0`, you should surround it with backticks:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE `" + libcard + "`" +
           " (Title INTEGER, " +
           " Director VARCHAR(255), " + 
           " dateBorrowed DATE, " + 
           " dueDate DATE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
try{

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");


      System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + libcard +
               "(Title INT(2), " +
               " Director VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " dateBorrowed DATE, " + 
               " dueDate DATE)"; 

      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
   }catch(SQLException se){

      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```